# The message doesn't appear on the mail while sending message via PHP

Tags: php, character, iconv

I have a problem about sending message on PHP. I need to use UTF-8 converter. When I use the iconv function, special characters on the message body doesn't appear
[image]

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
    /* Set e-mail recipient */
    $myemail = "example@example.com";

    /* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
    $name = check_input($_POST['inputName'], ".Your name");
    $email = check_input($_POST['inputEmail'], "Your E-mail");
    $subject = check_input($_POST['inputSubject'], "Your subject");
    $message = check_input($_POST['inputMessage'], "Your message");

    /* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
    if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
    {
        show_error("Invalid E-Mail");
    }
    /* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */

    $message = "
    Somebody sent a mail!

    Name: $name
    E mail: $email
    Subject: $subject

    Message:
    $message
    ";

    $subjectdecode = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-9", $subject);
    $messagedecode = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-9",$message);

    mail($myemail, $subjectdecode, $messagedecode);

   /* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
   header('Location:contact.html');
   exit();
   ?>
```